# What is this position called?

Tags: puzzles

I'm working on a problem for this cyber security camp, and we're doing a CTF right now. I have one problem left, and I'm almost certain in relates to chess, so I've come here for advice!

> Having determined the name of the bank, the FBI’s last step is to find Hax0r’s personal account. Strangely, when confronted with this question during interrogation, Hax0r agreed to tell us - but only if we played him in a game of chess. The FBI agreed, but when we got to the position on the board as shown below, Hax0r exclaimed, “You got it!” Can you figure it out what Hax0r meant? What is Hax0r’s account name in the offshore bank?

[image]

Comment: I am agreed to @RewanDemontay, this is not a chess problem, but being a former CEH, this problem makes me curious. As you can see, there is no black king on the board, I guess the all possible rank to each file [a-h], where there is a possibility of a "safe black king" could be the account number.

Comment: Not a chess problem, and probably a bit too pro-colonialism. Why doesn't Black have a king of its own? We don't like racism on this site

Comment: This isn't really a chess problem, and belongs on our sister site Puzzling Stack Exchange, [where it has been posted meanwhile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/100190/11110).

Answer (score 2):

The position doesn't make any sense.

But the pieces spell out several letters.
Clockwise from the top left: o,t,o,r

Maybe that's helpful?